# R: merging matrices (not data.frames)

Tags: r

merge is a very nice function: It merges matrices and data.frames, and returns a data.frame.

> Having rather big character matrices,
>   is there another good way to merge -
>   without data.frame conversion?

---

Comment 1:
A small function to merge a named vector with a matrix or data.frame. Elements of the vector can link to multiple entries in the matrix:

```
expand <- function(v,m,by.m,v.name='v',...) {
  df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(names(v),function(x) {
    pos <- which(m[,by.m] %in% v[x])
    cbind(x,m[pos,],...)
  }))
  colnames(df)[1] <- v.name
  df
}
```

Example:

```
v <- rep(letters,each=3)[seq_along(letters)]
names(v) <- letters
m <- data.frame(a=unique(v),b=seq_along(unique(v)),stringsAsFactors=F)
expand(v,m,'a')
```

Comment: Don't you just need `cbind` and `rbind`?

Comment: no, they are not sufficient: when having a m:n relationship, they would not expand/merge correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of match and cbind to do the equivalent of merge without conversion to data frame, a simple example:

```
st1 <- state.x77[ sample(1:50), ]
st2 <- as.matrix( USArrests )[ sample(1:50), ]

tmp1 <- match(rownames(st1), rownames(st2) )

st3 <- cbind( st1, st2[tmp1,] )
head(st3)
```

Keeping track of which columns you want, and merging whith many to 1 relationships or missing rows in one group require a bit more thought but are still possible.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK this is probably the most straightforward way to implement a matrix-merge, and you can probably create a function that merges the common columns into a key string to which you can apply `match()` if there are more than 1 columns to merge by.

Comment: match() and %in% are the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: you can also merge by row.names directly. `merge(x,y, by="row.names")`. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738773/r-how-to-merge-two-matrix-according-to-their-column-and-row-names)

Answer (score 3):

No, not without either (a) overwriting the merge function or (b) creating a new `merge.matrix()` S3 function (this would be the right approach to the problem).

You can see in the `merge` help:

> Value
>
> A data frame.

Also, the `merge.default` function:

```
> merge.default
function (x, y, ...) 
merge(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), ...)
```

Comment: Yes, I like the idea of adding a methods to the generic `merge()` function.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a `merge.Matrix` function in the `Matrix.utils` package.  This works on combinations of matrices as well as capital M Matrices, data.frames, etc.

The match solution is nice, but as someone pointed out **does not work on m:n relationships**.  It also does not implement the other features of `merge`, including `all.x`, `all.y`, etc.